# How to release an Azure DevOps artifact on GitHub Enterprise releases?

Tags: github, azure-pipelines, github-actions, github-enterprise, github-release

I like to release a pipeline artifact on GitHub Enterprise releases.

Here is the article I followed.

https://www.logitblog.com/releasing-an-azure-devops-artifact-on-github-releases/

The problem is that the "GitHubRelease" task is not compatible with GitHub Enterprise.

see this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11570

Any workaround to implement this function, like a script.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here is the bash task I used, but the task failed with this:
##[error]Bash exited with code '3'.

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Set the variables
      repo="client/SysInfo" # The repository name
      token=$(GithubToken) # Your personal access token
      tag="v1.0.0" # The tag name for the release
      title="My first release" # The title for the release
      body="This is a test release" # The description for the release
      file="README.md" # The path to the file to upload
      
      # Create the release
      url="https://github.azc.ext.xx.com/client/SysInfo/releases"
      response=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Authorization: token $token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"tag_name\":\"$tag\",\"name\":\"$title\",\"body\":\"$body\"}" $url)
      
      # Get the upload URL
      upload_url=$(echo $response | jq -r '.upload_url' | sed 's/{.*}//')
      
      # Upload the file
      curl -s -X POST -H "Authorization: token $token" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary @"$file" "$upload_url?name=$file"
```

Comment: may i know if the create release rest api works for you? let me know if you have queries.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT could you take look at this question? thanks. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77515406/github-create-release-api-call-returns-code-401

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT I tried create release rest api you recommanded, but the bash task failed.  I've updated the question with detail info, pls take a look, thanks.

Comment: i have replied and shared the sample in the new ticket, as you are using the template, the syntax is not correct, please check on the new ticket, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rest api [create-a-release](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/releases/releases?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-releases%22%7D) which support for github enterprise for the script.

[image]

I don't have github enterprise on hand, so i checked for github with rest api, sample code below, but it should work for enterprise as well(change the url).

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Set the variables
      repo="owner/repo3" # The repository name
      token=$(githubtoken) # Your personal access token
      tag="v1.0.0" # The tag name for the release
      title="My first release" # The title for the release
      body="This is a test release" # The description for the release
      file="README.md" # The path to the file to upload
      
      # Create the release
      url="https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/releases"
      response=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Authorization: token $token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"tag_name\":\"$tag\",\"name\":\"$title\",\"body\":\"$body\"}" $url)
      
      # Get the upload URL
      upload_url=$(echo $response | jq -r '.upload_url' | sed 's/{.*}//')
      
      # Upload the file
      curl -s -X POST -H "Authorization: token $token" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary @"$file" "$upload_url?name=$file"
```

[image]