# github create release API call returns code 401

Tags: github, azure-pipelines, github-actions, github-enterprise, github-release

Here is the template I used in the pipeline to create a GitHub Enterprise release.

I found code 401 means "unauthorized", but I don't know what's wrong with my setup, Is there any way to get the detailed cause of code 401?

```
- template: steps/git/github-create-release.yaml@templates
  parameters:
    githubRepo: client/SysInfo
    githubUrl: github.azc.ext.xx.com
    githubUser: winiotapp
    githubToken: $GithubToken
    assets: $BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY\\*.msi
    body: "System Information Release"
    draft: true
    name: "System Information"
    tagName: "1.0"
```

Here is the error message returned by template:

```
Creating a release at github.azc.ext.xx.com/api/v3/repos/client/SysInfo/releases with tagName [1.0] and name [System Information].
```

Here is the API call in the template that returned status code 401:

```
 RESPONSE=$(curl -u ${{ parameters.githubUser }}:${{ parameters.githubToken }} \
          --location --request POST ${{ parameters.githubUrl }}/api/v3/repos/${{ parameters.githubRepo }}/releases \
          --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
          --data "$(release_parameters)" \
          -s -w "%{http_code}")
      STATUS=$(tail -n1 <<< "$RESPONSE")
```

"winiotapp" is my GitHub enterprise user name and is the admin of repository client/SysInfo.

Here is the $GithubToken I generated.

[image]

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT could you take look at this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is caused by variable syntax in your yaml.

Please refer to my sample below for your reference, it works on my side. i have only github on hand, please change the url related if needed for github enterprise.

Main yaml:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
 repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: 'githubtest'
    ref: refs/heads/master


steps:
- template: github-create-release.yaml@templates
  parameters:
    githubRepo: "org/repo3"
    githubUrl: "https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo3/releases"
    githubUser: "testuser"
    githubToken: "$(GithubToken)"
    assets: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/README.md"  #use $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) if you store file here.
    releasebody: "System Information Release"
    draft: "true"
    releasename: "System Information"
    tagName: "1.0.1"
```

The template yaml, i echo the value for checking, you can remove the echo strings if needed.

```
parameters:
- name: 'githubRepo'
  type: string
- name: 'githubUrl'
  type: string
- name: 'githubUser'
  type: string
- name: 'githubToken'
  type: string
- name: 'assets'
  type: string
- name: 'releasebody'
  type: string
- name: 'draft'
  type: string
- name: 'releasename'
  type: string
- name: 'tagName'
  type: string

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Set the variables
      repo=${{ parameters.githubRepo }} # The repository name
      token=${{ parameters.githubToken }} # Your personal access token
      tag=${{ parameters.tagName }} # The tag name for the release
      title="${{ parameters.releasename }}" # The title for the release
      body="${{ parameters.releasebody }}" # The description for the release
      file=${{ parameters.assets }} # The path to the file to upload
      draft=${{ parameters.draft }}
      user=${{ parameters.githubUser }}

      echo $repo
      echo $tag
      echo $title
      echo $body
      echo $file
      echo $draft
      echo $user
      echo $token

      
      # Create the release
      url=${{ parameters.githubUrl }}

      echo $url
    
      response=$(curl -s -X POST -H "Authorization: token $token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"tag_name\":\"$tag\",\"name\":\"$title\",\"body\":\"$body\"}" $url)

      echo test
      
      # Get the upload URL
      upload_url=$(echo $response | jq -r '.upload_url' | sed 's/{.*}//')
      
      # Upload the file
      curl -s -X POST -H "Authorization: token $token" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary @"$file" "$upload_url?name=README.md"
```

You need to specify the **real msi file name** in yaml, not `*.msi`. If you would like to release all msi files, you can put them in a folder and zip it in task, transfer the zip file as parameter instead.

[image]

Comment: I created a "CreateRelease.sh" and ran it on git bash on my work machine. Do you know how to resolve this error?

Line 21:  upload_url=$(echo $response | jq -r '.upload_url' | sed 's/{.*}//')

CreateRelease.sh: line 21: jq: command not found

Comment: I ran the same bash script in pipeline. There is no "jq command not found" error, but this ##[error]Bash exited with code '3'

Comment: jq is pre-installed on Microsoft-Hosted agent, if you check the command on local machine, make sure you install the jq tool. You can check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53967693/how-to-run-jq-from-gitbash-in-windows).

Comment: For  ##[error]Bash exited with code '3', please first make sure all parameters are correctly  output(eg: echo in my template). The token should show as `***` as it's reacted, others have detail value.  If all parameter value are correct, please check the rest api usage.

Comment: Hi @Ming, may i know if there's any update? Let me know if you have any queries.